# Windows 10 Start Menu alarm center, and Cortana is not working

Tags: start-menu, windows-10-preview, cortana

I have no idea what is going on with my computer, but I can't open up my start menu, and the message center(or the alarm center).
I've tried restarting Windows Explorer, but it did not work for me.
Please help.

Comment: Have you activated Cortana :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Press Windows Key + R on your keyboard.
- Key in PowerShell and hit Enter.
- Right click on the PowerShell icon on the taskbar and select Run as
  Administrator.
- Now paste the following command in the Administrator: Windows
  PowerShell window and press Enter key:

  Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
- Wait for PowerShell to execute and complete the command. Ignore the
  few errors (in red color) that may pop up.
- When it finishes, try hitting Start and hopefully it’ll start
  working. If not, this solution won’t apply to you, unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

This is the the "start menu and Corrina not working, etc. " error. Having tried all other suggestions, this is what worked for me.  Installed ClassicWindowsShell then ran it although it seemed to not be working properly. I then ran Tweaker.com-Windows repair then rebooted in normal mode, not Safe Mode. The ClassicWindowsShell was working so I right-clicked on the TaskBar and double checked the settings and saved. My old icons on the task bar returned and I was back in action.

Comment: Using ClassicWindowsShell is not really fixing the OP's problem.